# Fastest way to retrieve NSManagedObjects based on a property in to-many relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am working on a CoreData stack which using sqlite as the underlying store. My schema looks something like this:

[image: Data Model]

An image can have multiple tags and a tag can belong to multiple images. My use-case is to be able to search images that match a particular tag name. The name attribute of tag is indexed.

I am using a FetchedResultsController in my ViewController to populate a CollectionView with desired images. Initially I pass the predicate as nil but when searching I need to show the relevant results i.e. images matching the tag with specified tag name. Below is my FetchedResultsController initialisation method.

```
func initialiseFetchedResultsControllerWith(_ predicate: NSPredicate) {

        //If the FRC is already initialised then just change the predicate and fetch again

        if fetchedResultsController != nil {
            fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        } else {
            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "SMImage")
            let timestampSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: false)
            fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [timestampSortDescriptor]
            fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

            fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: DataStoreController.sharedController.managedObjectContext!, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
            fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        }

        do {
            try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            print("Error in fetching image obbject via FRC => \(error)")
        }

    }
```

I need to pass a predicate to the FetchedResultsController to fetch the images. Two approaches come to my mind:

1. Get objectIDs all SMTags containing the search string and then querying the SMImages containing those objectIDs.

   ```
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObjectID>(entityName: "SMTag")
       fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@", text)
       fetchRequest.resultType =  NSFetchRequestResultType.managedObjectIDResultType
       var tagIDs: Array<NSManagedObjectID>? = nil

        do {
        tagIDs = try DataStoreController.sharedController.managedObjectContext!.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
        print("Error in retreiving tags with names = \(error)")
        }



        if tagIDs != nil {
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "tags IN %@", NSSet(array: tagIDs!))
        }
   ```

This approach does return tagIDs but returns no images.

2. The other approach is to directly search on SMTag's name of images using the predicate:

   ```
       predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY tags.name contains[cd] %@", text)
   ```

If you know of any better approach please do suggest. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of those approaches makes good use of Core Data. You have a many-to-many relationship, why not use it? A better approach is:

1. Get the single `SMTag` containing the search term. This would be very similar to the first part of your code snippet, except that you would fetch managed objects instead of object IDs.
2. Get all images associated with the tag by using the `images` relationship on `SMTag`. If you have a custom class for `SMTag` this would be something like `fetchedTag.images`. If not, it would be something like `fetchedTag.value(forKey:"images")`.

Comment: Thank you for replying @tom. The problem with this approach is that I am using a fetchResultsController so I need to pass a predicate to the fetchedResultsController to be able to retrieve the images. The approach you suggested won't work in that case. I have added more information to the question.

Comment: You're not required to use `NSFetchedResultsController`

Comment: Memory management becomes an issue if you try managing the a large number of objects. Also FetchedResultsController provides a lot of convenience in general. Could you guide me to a solution that works with FetchedResultsController?